# Stack menu with content (content to the right on large screens)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Taking into consideration the position of the content div (up middle), how can I achieve stacking the divs like this?

[image: Example]

Is there a way to do it with pure css or do I have to use jquery and move the div content out when on larger screens?

Comment: it is possible with bootstrap grid. see documentation.

Comment: Are the two menus combined on desktop or is one of them hidden?

Comment: they are combined, thanks for noting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be able to add a float:right to the content and float left to the menu when the screen width hits a certain size and it would make them stack side by side.

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .menu{
    float:left;
  }
  .content{
    float:right;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 menu">
      Menu 1
    </div> 
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 content">
      Content
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 menu">
      Menu 2
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```